# MS Report Builder Expression not using group or parameter

Tags: reporting-services, report, builder

My tablix is suppose to return 900 report cards (for school district), the one Row Group is set the UserName (students), which does return the correct grouping of one page per student.  But, the data does not update to match the UserName.  Each student is suppose to have its own grades on each page.  How do I write the expression to get the UserName data or data that references the Group? 
 Here is what I have...

=SUM(IIF(Fields!TeacherPeriod.value = "0" And Fields!StudentPeriod.Value = "4" And Fields!SkillOne.value < "5" And Fields!SkillOne.value > "0" And Fields!UserName.value = Parameters!ReportParameter1.value, Fields!SkillOne.value, 0),"DataSet1")

I added "Parameters!ReportParameter1.value" as the parameter is also set to UserName, but it returns the same data for all students.

Comment: Can you edit you post to show an example, it's not clear to me what the problem is. Show the data in your dataset and expected output too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the group scope to your `=Sum()` expression to reference to a group. Lets say you have a dataset (**Dataset1**) and a grouping with the name **StudentGrouping**. The first expression will return always the same, but the second one is based on the grouping:

```
'Sum the whole Dataset
=Sum(IIF(Fields!TeacherPeriod.Value = "0" And Fields!StudentPeriod.Value = "4", Fields!SkillONe.Value, 0), "DataSet1")

'Sum the grouping
=Sum(IIF(Fields!TeacherPeriod.Value = "0" And Fields!StudentPeriod.Value = "4", Fields!SkillONe.Value, 0), "StudentGrouping")
```

Comment: Another issue I'm trying to figure out in this report...  When the SUM returns false, I would like to print a string instead of 0.  I realize this does not work because of what SUM is doing (adding integers), but SUM is the only expression working (IIF does not work for some reason).  Is there a way to convert to a string?

Comment: There are a few ways to do this, but I am not exactly sure what you want to do. You can convert the endresult to a string for example `=CStr(Sum(IIF(Condition, Value, 0)))`. You can also do `=IIF(Sum(IIF(Condition, Value, 0))=0, "NoValue", Sum(IIF(Condition, Value, 0)))`. You can also go under properties of the textbox **Number > Currency** and check the **Show zero as "-/(None)"**